# Failed to start OMI CIM Server. [LINUX]

Tags: system, database-administration

```
systemd: Starting OMI CIM Server...
systemd: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/omi/bin/support/installssllinks: No such file or directory
systemd: omid.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
systemd: Failed to start OMI CIM Server.
systemd: Unit omid.service entered failed state.
systemd: omid.service failed.
systemd: omid.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
systemd: Stopped OMI CIM Server.
```

This error is recorded on the logs like continuously everyday. Can this possibly affect the connection between the  database servers?

Answer (score 0):

Check with `df -h` if any directory filled up 100%. That CIM error comes up when OMID and OMSAGENT both agents are unable to restart.

Comment: Maybe we could create a tag "omi" like for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934395/connection-from-linux-omi-omicli-to-windows-wmi-fails-with-dmtf-related-error ?